# How do I get a specific key value from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

This is my first time using any kind of APIs, and I'm just starting out in JS. I want to get the status of a server within a server hosting panel, to do this I need to log in (API/Core/Login), get a the value of a key called sessionID, then send that value to /API/Core/GetUpdates to get a response. When trying to pass the sessionID to GetUpdates, it sends undefined instead of the sessionID, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong when trying to reference the key value. Here's my code:

```js
var loginurl = "https://proxyforcors.workers.dev/?https://the.panel/API/ADSModule/Servers/83e9181/API/Core/Login";

var loginRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
loginRequest.open("POST", loginurl);

loginRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
loginRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

loginRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (loginRequest.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(loginRequest.status);
    console.log(loginRequest.responseText);
  }
};

var logindata = '{"username":"API", "password":"password", "token":"", "rememberMe":"true"}';

loginRequest.send(logindata);

var statusurl = "https://proxyforcors.workers.dev/?https://the.panel/API/ADSModule/Servers/83e9181/API/Core/GetUpdates";

var statusreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
statusreq.open("POST", statusurl);

statusreq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
statusreq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

statusreq.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (statusreq.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(statusreq.status);
    console.log(statusreq.responseText);
  }
};

var statusdata = `{"SESSIONID":"${loginRequest.responseText.sessionID}"}`; // Line I'm having problems with

statusreq.send(statusdata);

console.log(loginRequest.responseText.sessionID)
```

Here's the response of /API/Core/Login

```
{"success":true,"permissions":[],"sessionID":"1d212b7a-a54d-4e91-abde-9e1f7b0e03f2","rememberMeToken":"5df7cf99-15f5-4e01-b804-6e33a65bd6d8","userInfo":{"ID":"034f33ba-3bca-47c7-922a-7a0e7bebd3fd","Username":"API","IsTwoFactorEnabled":false,"Disabled":false,"LastLogin":"\/Date(1639944571884)\/","GravatarHash":"8a5da52ed126447d359e70c05721a8aa","IsLDAPUser":false},"result":10}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for awhile.

Comment: You need to call `JSON.parse()` to convert the JSON to an object.

Comment: And you have to put that code in the callback function, not at top-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responseText` is the text representation of the `JSON` response.

Either use `JSON.parse(logindata.responseText)` to get the JSON data or use `logindata.responseJSON`

Comment: I've added `var obj = JSON.parse(loginRequest.responseText);` but I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: Fixed by putting the last 3 lines in the first function